# Crawl .config files

Tags: 2013, search, crawling, xml, fast-search

I have a fileshare with several thousands .config files (xml files) - and several thousands of other files.
I added the .config files to the allowed file-types and restarted search.

Apparently the search crawler (SP2013) parses the content and discovers that they are application/xml - thats why I can't search for tag names, eg. `<settings>` because only xml values are indexed.

I tried to override the xml mimetype with

```
New-SPEnterpriseSearchFileFormat -SearchApplication $ssa config "Config" text/plain
```

But that does not change my result...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at adding an XML iFilter? Depending on the coding you could index the values and  would be a crawled property.

The other alternative would be to write a Content Processing Callout. Register the callout trigger for FileExtension="config" and you can perform the processing yourself.

Comment: I read that you cant "overwrite" ifilters - there is a xml ifilter out of the box.

Comment: The CPC is too slow for 100-500k files.

Comment: You can't overwrite the Document Handlers, but I think you can change the registration for iFilters. I haven't tried yet. Do you want crawled properties of just free text?

Comment: Free text would be great. Regarding overwrite: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219577.aspx it states "You can extend the initial collection of file formats that SharePoint 2013 can parse by adding third-party filter-based format handlers, known as iFilters. You cannot override a built-in format handler by installing a third-party iFilter."

Comment: Any clues for the free text part?